# Escape date command from within printf

Tags: bash

Every so often I erase the SD card of my RaspberryPI and start from scratch from the latest image. To make the initial configuration process faster, I have created a bash script that I can use to initialize the PI with many defaults. I'm having trouble creating a `backup-database.sh` bash script from within my startup bash script.

This step should create a new file called `backup-database.sh`.

```
printf "
#calculate the backup filename
backupFile=`date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`.sql
echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`: \"Creating database backup\"
#create full backup of entire database, give it today's date
mysqldump -uroot -pNOT_MY_ACTUAL_PASSWORD --all-databases > /var/db-backups/\$backupFile

#upload the backup to dropbox
echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`: \"Uploading backup to dropbox\"
/var/db-backups/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /var/db-backups/\$backupFile db/\$backupFile
" > /var/db-backups/backup-database.sh
```

The problem is, the contents of `backup-database.sh` look like this after I run the above command:

```
#calculate the backup filename
backupFile=2018-02-19--19-59-11.sql
echo 2018-02-19--19-59-11: "Creating database backup"
#create full backup of entire database, give it today's date
mysqldump -uroot -pNOT_MY_ACTUAL_PASSWORD --all-databases > /var/db-backups/$backupFile

#upload the backup to dropbox
echo 2018-02-19--19-59-11: "Uploading backup to dropbox"
/var/db-backups/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /var/db-backups/$backupFile db/$backupFile
```

I want `backup-database.sh` to look like this:

```
#calculate the backup filename
backupFile=`date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`.sql
echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`: "Creating database backup"
#create full backup of entire database, give it today's date
mysqldump -uroot -pNOT_MY_ACTUAL_PASSWORD --all-databases > /var/db-backups/$backupFile
#upload the backup to dropbox
echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`: "Uploading backup to dropbox"
/var/db-backups/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /var/db-backups/$backupFile db/$backupFile
```

All of the dates are being inserted when I CREATE the `backup-database.sh` file, but I need those date lines to be inserted literally so that the date is calculated when `backup-database.sh` is executed. I've tried escaping the backticks `, inserting double percents %%, etc.

How can I correctly escape the date command within the printf command so that it is written literally to the `backup-database.sh` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using a [here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html):

```
cat > /var/db-backups/backup-database.sh <<'EOF'
#calculate the backup filename
backupFile=`date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`.sql
echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`: "Creating database backup"
#create full backup of entire database, give it today's date
mysqldump -uroot -pNOT_MY_ACTUAL_PASSWORD --all-databases > /var/db-backups/$backupFile
#upload the backup to dropbox
echo `date '+%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S'`: "Uploading backup to dropbox"
/var/db-backups/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /var/db-backups/$backupFile db/$backupFile
EOF
```

Quoting the tag (`EOF`) ensures that the lines don't get expanded before the actual redirection so there is no need to quote them.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you have to escape the backticks and add a % before all format characters.

```
printf "
#calculate the backup filename
backupFile=\`date '+%%Y-%%m-%%d--%%H-%%M-%%S'\`.sql
echo \`date '+%%Y-%%m-%%d--%%H-%%M-%%S'\`: \"Creating database backup\"
#create full backup of entire database, give it today's date
mysqldump -uroot -pNOT_MY_ACTUAL_PASSWORD --all-databases > /var/db-backups/\$backupFile

#upload the backup to dropbox
echo \`date '+%%Y-%%m-%%d--%%H-%%M-%%S'\`: \"Uploading backup to dropbox\"
/var/db-backups/dropbox_uploader.sh upload /var/db-backups/\$backupFile db/\$backupFile
" > /var/db-backups/backup-database.sh
```

the backslashes are needed to escape the special meaning of the ` character and %% prints a literal % in printf instead of using it as a format string

Comment: *Technically* that works, but I wouldn't describe it as something with even a remote relationship with best practices.

Comment: this is the only working solution for me.